# Why are antidepressants used to treat OCD?

Tags: psychiatrist-psychiatry, biochemistry

I was wondering why antidepressants are used to treat OCD. I would like to know it from a biological/ biochemical point of view.

Edit:
Since I've been asked, I was specifically interested in the biochemical point of view, but it seemed that there's a lack of literature regarding this aspect, as pointed out by one of the answers.

Thanks

Comment: Hi JackV, welcome to Medical Sciences. Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in [the help center](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot of overlap between OCD and other anxiety disorders, which are also treated with antidepressants, and possibly depression as well (which itself often overlaps with anxiety). Some papers discussing these relationships and categorization:

*Bartz, J. A., & Hollander, E. (2006). Is obsessive–compulsive disorder an anxiety disorder?. Progress in neuro-psychopharmacology and biological psychiatry, 30(3), 338-352.*

*Bienvenu, O. J., Samuels, J. F., Wuyek, L. A., Liang, K. Y., Wang, Y., Grados, M. A., ... & Nestadt, G. (2012). Is obsessive–compulsive disorder an anxiety disorder, and what, if any, are spectrum conditions? A family study perspective. Psychological medicine, 42(1), 1-13.*

*Gentes, E. L., & Ruscio, A. M. (2011). A meta-analysis of the relation of intolerance of uncertainty to symptoms of generalized anxiety disorder, major depressive disorder, and obsessive–compulsive disorder. Clinical psychology review, 31(6), 923-933.*

*Stein, D. J., Fineberg, N. A., Bienvenu, O. J., Denys, D., Lochner, C., Nestadt, G., ... & Phillips, K. A. (2010). Should OCD be classified as an anxiety disorder in DSM‐V?. Depression and anxiety, 27(6), 495-506.*

"Antidepressant" is just a category of psychiatric drugs that happen to work for depression; there's nothing about their mechanism that limits them to working only in that category.

As far as the biological/biochemical point of view... well, that's something that remains not well understood for depression, let alone anxiety disorders or OCD. We know a lot about how antidepressants work on a molecular level; for example, [SSRIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_serotonin_reuptake_inhibitor) are selective serotonin reuptake inhibitors: their molecular function is right in the name, they block serotonin reuptake (and, in particular, they are selective for serotonin reuptake over other monoamines like dopamine). The missing link is *why exactly does blocking serotonin reuptake relieve symptoms of depression (or OCD)*: we don't really know. There are multiple theories that are all difficult to test because it is not straightforward to interfere with only one mechanistic pathway.

So, if we don't know what the biological mechanism is, how is it possible to use these drugs? Well, they aren't used because we know exactly how they work, but because studies of actual people with the thing being treated show that they do better with the drug than with a placebo. Some examples of reviews/meta-analyses:

*Gorman, J. M., & Kent, J. M. (1999). SSRIs and SNRIs: broad spectrum of efficacy beyond major depression. Journal of Clinical Psychiatry, 60(4), 33-39.*

*Greist, J. H., Jefferson, J. W., Kobak, K. A., Katzelnick, D. J., & Serlin, R. C. (1995). Efficacy and tolerability of serotonin transport inhibitors in obsessive-compulsive disorder. A meta-analysis. Archives of General Psychiatry, 52(1), 53-60.*

*Greist, J. H., & Jefferson, J. W. (1998). Pharmacotherapy for obessive-compulsive disorder. The British Journal of Psychiatry, 173(S35), 64-70.*

*Pizarro, M., Fontenelle, L. F., Paravidino, D. C., Yuecel, M., Miguel, E. C., & de Menezes, G. B. (2014). An updated review of antidepressants with marked serotonergic effects in obsessive–compulsive disorder. Expert opinion on pharmacotherapy, 15(10), 1391-1401.*

Brains are complicated, we don't quite know how they work yet, so it's not surprising that it's much easier to measure the psychiatric effects of a drug on patients than to know how exactly it works. Importantly, the reverse is true, too: lots of drugs that have a well-known biological mechanism of action that supports their use as treatments for, say, cancer (especially in animal models), don't actually work when given to people, so they aren't used.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for